# React - How to execute function from child functional component

Tags: reactjs

I need your help with a Component I need to make re-usable in React. Right now I have a Settings page where people can configure some connections to other applications. The different application-settings look somewhat the same, but not completely. Ofcourse I can fix this with props, but also the `buttonClick` code is different, and I cant figure out how. Here is an example of 1 setting:

```
const DarkSky = ({auth}) => {
    const [config, setConfig] = useState(getLocalStorage('darksky') || {api_key: '', success: false});

    const saveConfig = async () => {
        const data = await makeAPICall('/api/darksky/current', 'GET', null, await auth.getAccessToken())
        setConfig({api_key: config.api_key, success: true})
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setLocalStorage('darksky', config)
    }, [config])


    const configHandler = (event) => setConfig({...config, 'api_key': event.target.value});

    const buttonClickHandler = (event) => saveConfig()

    let formItems = [{
        name: 'apikey',
        type: 'input',
        label: 'API key',
        value: config.api_key,
        changehandler: configHandler
    }] 

    return <div><h2>DarkSky connection</h2>

        <DefaultFormRow data={formItems} buttons={[{id: 'saveapikey', click: buttonClickHandler, buttonclass: (config.success ? 'success' : 'danger'), disabled: false, text: 'Sla API key op'}]} />
        <p>Config correct: {config.success === true ? 'Ja' : 'Nee'} </p>
    </div>  

}
```

In this (working) example, there are controlled inputs (formItems) which update the config-state with this code:
`const configHandler = (event) => setConfig({...config, 'api_key': event.target.value});`. I can make this reusable by doing something like: 
`const configHandler = (event) => setConfig({...config, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});`

Then there is a buttonClick handler which fires after people click on the save button. In this case it fires `saveConfig()`, but in other cases, it needs to do something else. If I pass it from the parent Component (the settings page), this function will execute from the parent Component and I cannot access the state of this child component.

How should you guys do this? I dont think I can make a function execute in the child class right? And I dont want to add all those different states in the parent class, because I like this clean look (state in its own component).

I dont know if I have been clear, I'll add more details if you guys ask.

EDIT: At this moment I have this:

```
const APIManagement = ({auth}) => {
    return <div>
        <SolarEdge />
        <Tado />
        <DarkSky />
        <Enelogic />

    </div> 
}
```

The different Components here look A LOT like eachother, so it would be nice if I could have something like this:

```
const APIManagement = ({auth}) => {

    const saveFunction1 = () => {how to save tado settings here}
    const saveFunction2 = () => {how to save enelogic settings here}
    const saveFunction3 = () => {how to save darksky settings here}
    const saveFunction4 = () => {how to save solaredge settings here}

    return <div>
        <APISetting title='Tado' saveFunction={saveFunction1}/>
        <APISetting title='Enelogic' saveFunction={saveFunction2}/>
        <APISetting title='DarkSky' saveFunction={saveFunction3}/>
        <APISetting title='SolarEdge' saveFunction={saveFunction4}/>

    </div>

}
```

EDIT2: The settings are getting persisted by adding it to the localStorage from the browser by the save function:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setLocalStorage('darksky', config)
    }, [config])
```

Comment: Pass the state of child class to parent class when trigger `buttonClickHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

In a child functional component you can pass props object consisting of function. In that function pass your child functional component state there and set the state there in the parent component and when it renders it will pass back the new state to functional component.

Parent class :-

```
parentFunction = () => {
   //set your state here
}
render() {
   return(
     <DarkSky auth={xyz} parentFunction={this.parentFunction} {...this.state}/>
   )
}
```

child functional component :-

```
const DarkSky = ({auth, parentFunction, state}) => {
}
```

As you have been using react hooks and it has a feature of isolating the state. so what you can do is make a reusable component (custom hook):-

```
//put this is another js file
export function useConfig(key, defaultConfig) {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState(getLocalStorage(key) || 
  defaultConfig);

  useEffect(() => {
        setLocalStorage(key, config)
    }, [config])
  return config;
}

import { useConfig } from '/js/file/path'
const APISetting = ({title, saveFunction}) => {
    let config = useConfig(title, {api_key: '', success: false})
    const saveConfig = async () => {
        const data = await makeAPICall(`/api/${title}/current`, 'GET', null, await auth.getAccessToken())
//        setConfig({api_key: config.api_key, success: true})
          const newConfig = useConfig({api_key: config.api_key, success: true})
          saveFunction(newConfig);
    } 

    const configHandler = (event) => { config = useConfig({...config, 'api_key': event.target.value}) };

    const buttonClickHandler = (event) => saveConfig()

    let formItems = [{
        name: 'apikey',
        type: 'input',
        label: 'API key',
        value: config.api_key,
        changehandler: configHandler
    }] 

    return <div><h2>{title} connection</h2>

        <DefaultFormRow data={formItems} buttons={[{id: 'saveapikey', click: buttonClickHandler, buttonclass: (config.success ? 'success' : 'danger'), disabled: false, text: 'Sla API key op'}]} />
        <p>Config correct: {config.success === true ? 'Ja' : 'Nee'} </p>
    </div>  

}

In your parent component you will get like this :-

const APIManagement = ({auth}) => {

    const saveFunction1 = (config) => {console.log('the config is', config)}
    const saveFunction2 = () => {how to save enelogic settings here}
    const saveFunction3 = () => {how to save darksky settings here}
    const saveFunction4 = () => {how to save solaredge settings here}

    return <div>
        <APISetting title='Tado' saveFunction={saveFunction1}/>
        <APISetting title='Enelogic' saveFunction={saveFunction2}/>
        <APISetting title='DarkSky' saveFunction={saveFunction3}/>
        <APISetting title='SolarEdge' saveFunction={saveFunction4}/>

    </div>

}
```

Comment: Yeah, but If I do that I have to manage all the different states from the child components in the parent class. I understand that it would work, but is there no other way? So that the state of the child func component can stay there?

Comment: You are calling saveConfig to save the config for each case and you want the same config which was saved when configHandler is called. right?

Comment: I editted the topic with some explanation. I dont want to have data accessible in parent, but the child component should be, as much as possible, reusable, so I dont have duplicate code. Those different 'setting-components' have almost the same code, only the saveConfig function differs.

Comment: you are saying your previous config is getting persist ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry,  the save-function saves it on browserstorage (localStorage), so that it gets persisted.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        setLocalStorage('darksky', config)
    }, [config])